# Missing day in Windows date output

Tags: windows, date

I have two Windows 7 laptops (different manufacturers), both running Windows 7 and **both set to the same regional locale**: ***English (Australia)***.  On one, in a Command Prompt window, the 'date' command gives both the day and the date (e.g., Fri 04/04/2015), but on the other only the date (i.e., 04/09/2015).

Any ideas why?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats Tab
```

That's where the systemwide "long date" format is specified. To include a "Fri" before the date, pick one with dddd at the front I believe.

Comment: It was the short date that works in my Win 8.1, M/d/yyyy show the date, MM/dd/yyyy doesn't (even though M/d/yyyy shouldn't have shown the day of the week)

Comment: @Collin Driscoll, I tried modifying the "long date" format, but the result was the same.

Comment: @Martheen: your suggestion worked!!!  Thanks very much!  How counterintuitive.  Appreciate your assistance.